# How to create unit test for testing data insertion methods with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, unit-testing

I'm trying to create unit tests for methods that insert data into a SQL Server database in ASP.NET MVC. I've got several `ActionResult` methods that write data into my SQL Server database. One of these methods is this the following:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddApi(ApiRedirect model)
    {
        try
        {
            List<ApiRedirect> list = dbProducts.ApiRedirects.ToList();
            int companyID = dbProducts.Companies.Where(x => x.CompanyName == model.Company.CompanyName).FirstOrDefault().CompanyID;
            int mappingID = dbProducts.MappingNames.Where(x => x.Name == model.MappingName.Name).FirstOrDefault().MappingID;
            ApiRedirect api = new ApiRedirect();
            api.ApiName = model.ApiName;
            api.CompanyID = companyID;
            api.ApiURL2 = model.ApiURL2;
            api.MappingID = mappingID;
            api.ResponseType = model.ResponseType;

            dbProducts.ApiRedirects.Add(api);
            dbProducts.SaveChanges();

            return View ();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

However when I try to this in my test project like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class ApiRedirectTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void AddApiRedirect()
    {
        //Arrange
        var controller = new ApiBrokerController();
        ApiRedirect model = new ApiRedirect();
        model.ApiName = "UnitTest";
        model.CompanyID = 1;
        model.ApiURL2 = "www.UnitTest.com/API";
        model.MappingID = 1;
        model.ResponseType = "json";

        //Act
        controller.AddApi(model);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

[image]

I would like some test that writes code, checks if code is inserted in database and delete afterwards. What is the best way to do that?

**UPDATE**
I've added MVC reference to my project and now I get the following error:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The best way is to mock your repositories and do not write data to your database through your unit tests.

Comment: To fix your error, add the System.web.mvc framework to your unit test
`PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`

Comment: If you want a unit test, you mock the database. If you want an integration test, you inject an in-memory database. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are talking about is an integration test not a  unit test.

you will have:

- a call which creates some data
- another which does the actual test / asserts against your criteria
- a final one which deletes the test data created in step one.

You have a number of ways of doing this, one in code, you write code which talks to endpoints only, you don't need to instantiate a controller at all.

What you must ensure you have is a way to create / delete data in an API kind of way, so you need endpoints which do this.

If you don't want to write code, you can also use something like Postman which can quite nicely orchestrate all this. This gives you the certainty that everything works, from the endpoints which clients will use, all the way down to database.

Answer (score 0):

**Error number 1**

> To fix your error, add the System.web.mvc framework to your unit test
> PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc – gh9 20 mins ago

**Error Number 2**

You now need to upgrade the System.web version to 5.2 from 4.0

Try adding this [Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/5.2.3)

Comment: How do I do this? Max version is 4.0 when I try to add?